"Failed to get upload status for /mnt/data/*filename*" Issue downloading files generated by ChatGPT
I'm working on a project where I need to extract employee information from an HTML file, save this data into a JSON file, and download employee images to a specific folder. I used ChatGPT to generate a Python script for this purpose. The JSON file seems to be created, but I'm encountering issues with downloading and saving the images. Additionally, when I try to download the files from ChatGPT's environment, I receive an error message:

Failed to get upload status for /mnt/data/FileName.

I have searched similar problem on ChatGpt forum and found this thread. No solution till now. Can anybody help?

Yep!
Make sure your Python script for downloading and saving images is correctly implemented. Here's an example script that extracts employee information from an HTML file, saves it to a JSON file, and downloads employee images to a specific folder (edit it to suit yours):
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# Define the HTML file path
html_file_path = 'path_to_your_html_file.html'

# Read and parse the HTML file
with open(html_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')

# Extract employee data
employees = []
for employee in soup.find_all('div', class_='employee'):
    name = employee.find('h2').text
    position = employee.find('p', class_='position').text
    image_url = employee.find('img')['src']

    employees.append({
        'name': name,
        'position': position,
        'image_url': image_url
    })

# Save employee data to a JSON file
json_file_path = '/mnt/data/employees.json'
with open(json_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json.dump(employees, json_file, indent=4)

# Download and save employee images
image_folder_path = '/mnt/data/employee_images'
os.makedirs(image_folder_path, exist_ok=True)

for employee in employees:
    image_url = employee['image_url']
    image_response = requests.get(image_url)

    if image_response.status_code == 200:
        image_name = os.path.basename(image_url)
        image_path = os.path.join(image_folder_path, image_name)
        with open(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
            image_file.write(image_response.content)

print("Employee data and images saved successfully.")

To download the files created in the ChatGPT environment, you need to ensure that the files are properly saved and accessible. If you encounter the "Failed to get upload status" error, do this:
Make sure the file path is correct and that the file indeed exists in the specified location.
Make sure that the environment where the script is running has the necessary permissions to read and write to the specified directory.
If the error persists, try renaming the file or using a different directory path to see if the issue is related to a specific file name or path.
Verify if the environment where the code is executed has any restrictions or specific requirements for file access.
Finally, after making sure the script works correctly and the files are saved in the expected location, use the appropriate method to download the files. In ChatGPT's environment, the files saved in /mnt/data/ can be downloaded using the provided download links.
That should do it.
Good luck!

This maybe due GPT-4o free and OPENAI may had some restriction cause we are using Free responses.
If you really want to save the file, here's how i did it:
install the dependences:
You'll need the requests library for downloading images. You can install it by opening your terminal or command prompt and typing:
pip install requests

create new PYTHON file and copy the code from CHATGPT to python file
also remove the:-

/mnt/data/

from the last lines of code from CHATGPT
save the python file and use command
python FileName.py
and then use this to make sure file is saved in dir.
Get-Content .\FileName.py

after that look for file in the Dir. where your python file is saved.
This method worked for me to save the PPTX file and Docx file>
Cheers!
In case of pptx or docx (PowerPoint or Word Documents) Fil use this to install dependencies:
pip install python-pptx python-docx


So you are talking about doing things locally?
